# keras.optimizers.Adam "not found module" error when running code form GPU in Colab

Tags: python, keras, gpu, google-colaboratory, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run a code importing keras.optimizers Adam. I want to do it from GPU as I need to make a long training. If I run normally it works, but every time I change the runtime enviroment to GPU, it doesn't find the module "Adam" and gives me the error below. I'm using keras 2.2.4 due to compatibilities with other libraries:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ca97e5a6925a> in <module>()
      8 from keras.models import Sequential
      9 from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Convolution2D, Permute
---> 10 from keras.optimizers import Adam
     11 import keras.backend as K
     12 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Adam' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py)


NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 
and not
from keras.optimizers import Adam

Answer (score 3):

Change the line:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

and it'll work.

Comment: thank you! now it works! but now I have the same problem with the module keras-rl. It can't find the module. I'm using keras-rl 0.4.2, I've seen in another post that upgrading to keras-rl2 would solve it but I'm worried it woudn't be compatible with the other modules.

Comment: Upgrade to solve your problem. If another problem arises, you can ask again @AlejandroDelPozzoEscalera